# Bounded linear operator on $\mathbf{C}[-1,1]$ and its norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $A:\mathbf{C}[-1,1]\to \mathbf{C}[-1,1]$ be a linear operator defined as
$$Ax(t)=\frac{x(t)+x(-t)}{2},$$
where $\mathbf{C}[-1,1]$ is the usual space of continuous real-valued functions over $[-1,1]$. I want to show that $A$ is bounded and calculate $\|A\|$. For boundedness, I am stuck after applying the triangle inequality.

Comment: The norm is the usual supremum norm defined on C[a,b].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to show that the operator A is bounded. Secondly, I want to calculate the operator norm ||A||.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we want to compute $\lVert A \rVert$ (and in particular, show that it is finite). So, let's look at the definition:

$$\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbf{C}[-1,1] \\ \lVert x \rVert = 1}} \lVert Ax \rVert.$$

In particular, we see that in order to compute the value of $\lVert A \rVert$, we'll need to understand the value of $\lVert Ax \rVert$ for arbitrary $x$. Let's try to do that.

Let $x \in \mathbf{C}[-1,1]$ be arbitrary and assume $\lVert x \rVert = 1$. Now by definition of the sup norm,

$$\lVert Ax \rVert = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert (Ax)(t) \rvert.$$

By definition of $A$, we have

$$\lVert Ax \rVert = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert (Ax)(t) \rvert = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \left\lvert \frac{x(t) + x(-t)}{2} \right\rvert.$$

We have an absolute value of a sum, so it seems worthwhile to try applying the triangle inequality. This gives

$$\lVert Ax \rVert = \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \left\lvert \frac{x(t) + x(-t)}{2} \right\rvert \leq \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \left(\left\lvert \frac{x(t)}{2} \right\rvert + \left\lvert \frac{x(-t)}{2} \right\rvert\right) = \frac{1}{2} \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} ( \lvert x(t) \rvert + \lvert x(-t) \rvert ).$$

The sup of a sum is bounded by the sum of the sups, so we get

$$\lVert Ax \rVert \leq \frac{1}{2} \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} ( \lvert x(t) \rvert + \lvert x(-t) \rvert ) \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(t) \rvert + \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(-t) \rvert \right).$$

Now we can notice that $\sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(t) \rvert$ is (by definition) just $\lVert x \rVert$! In fact, $\sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(-t) \rvert$ is exactly the same quantity (because $\{-t : t \in [-1,1]\} = [-1,1]$). So, we have

$$\lVert Ax \rVert \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(t) \rvert + \sup_{t \in [-1,1]} \lvert x(-t) \rvert \right) = \frac{1}{2} (\lVert x \rVert + \lVert x \rVert) = \lVert x \rVert = 1.$$

Now, since $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that

$$\lVert A \rVert = \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbf{C}[-1,1] \\ \lVert x \rVert = 1}} \lVert Ax \rVert \leq \sup_{\substack{x \in \mathbf{C}[-1,1] \\ \lVert x \rVert = 1}} 1 = 1.$$

In particular, we now know that $\lVert A \rVert$ is finite! Because the inequalities we applied are fairly mild, we should guess that $\lVert A \rVert$ actually equals $1$. The easiest way to prove this would be to find some $x \in \mathbf{C}[-1,1]$ such that $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and $\lVert Ax \rVert = 1$. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: (+1) Really good answer. As a follow up, to find such function $x \in \mathbb C[-1,1]$, I suggest (as a hint) the OP to think about constant functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi(t):[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$
be a continuous mapping. The operator $$T_\varphi (f)=f\circ \varphi$$ is a bounded on $C[-1,1],$ because $$\|T_\varphi(f)|_\infty =\|f\circ \varphi\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty $$ Hence $\|T_\varphi\|\le 1.$
The operator $T$ in OP is equal $$T={1\over 2}I+{1\over 2}T_\varphi ,\quad \varphi(t)=-t$$ Therefore by the triangle inequality we get $$\|T\|\le {1\over 2}\|I\|+{1\over 2}\|T_\varphi \|\le 1$$ The norm is actually  equal $1.$ There is an obvious choice of $f$ on which the norm is attained for an arbitrary $\varphi.$ In the OP there are more possibilities as for  every even function $f$ we get $T(f)=f.$